# Can I pass to build command flag and read inside code?

Tags: go

I want in init function to execute one of those two lines

```
func init() {
    log.SetPrefix(">>>>>>>>>>>>>   ")


    log.SetOutput(ioutil.Discard)
}
```

How to achieve something similiar to C and macro definition in make file ?
I build go program like go build my_project and I don't have any custom make file. Can I pass to build command flag and read inside code ?

Comment: See section "Build Constraints" in http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/. But please think of a different solution first (maybe command line flags?). Go is not C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a string variable that you can test. Then set that string variable using `-X` passed to the linker. For example:

```
package main

var MODE string

func main() {
    if MODE == "PROD" {
        println("I'm in prod mode")
    } else {
        println("I'm NOT in prod mode")
    }

}
```

Now, if you build this with just `go build`, `MODE` will be `""`. But you can also build it this way:

```
go build -ldflags "-X main.MODE PROD"
```

And now `MODE` will be `"PROD"`. You can use that to modify your logic based on build settings. I generally use this technique to set version numbers in the binary; but it can be used for all kinds of build-time configuration. Note that it can only set strings. So you couldn't make `MODE` a bool or integer.

---

You can also achieve this with tags, which are slightly more complicated to set up, but much more powerful. Create three files:

#### main.go

```
package main

func main() {
    doThing()
}
```

#### main_prod.go

```
// +build prod

package main

func doThing() {
    println("I'm in prod mode")
}
```

#### main_devel.go

```
// +build !prod

package main

func doThing() {
    println("I'm NOT in prod mode")
}
```

Now when you build with `go build`, you'll get your `main_devel.go` version (the filename doesn't matter; just the `// +build !prod` line at the top). But you can get a production build by building with `go build -tags prod`.

See the section on Build Constraints in the [build](http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/) documentation.

Comment: Glad I saw this answer! I was about to research how to do something like this in Go specifically for version numbers and commit tagging at build!